# Is there any RAPID instruction to save image as variable in YuMi integrated vision without using RobotStudio?

Tags: robotic-arm, computer-vision, industrial-robot, communication

- I want to perceive the images from the cameras embedded in YuMi IRB 14000 arms and store them as videos, in Ubuntu **without** using [ABB RobotStudio](https://new.abb.com/products/robotics/robotstudio).
- is there any way to do that? if yes how can I do that please?
- I have read [**RAPID Technical Reference Manual 3HAC050917-001**](https://library.e.abb.com/public/b227fcd260204c4dbeb8a58f8002fe64/Rapid_instructions.pdf?x-sign=f79v/883X1nHGc8fqH+WAJ2F30y/M6TZfYUuPuQpP+jeMBygouyGg+WSj8A9Otry) but didn't find a way to obtain the image array with rapid!
- Note: they mentioned in page 57 that : `CamReqImage` (Camera Request Image) orders the camera to acquire an image, but they didn't mention how to obtain that image!